# How to replace styled <p> tag in HTML Table for Use in Outlook

Tags: css, outlook, html-table, html-email

How can I achieve the same styling effect you see being used below on the paragraph element for use in Outlook? As you probably know Outlook does not support padding and generally handles the paragraph tag very poorly. Anyway, in Outlook the paragraph element stretches horizontally to both edges of the table. I have successfully used margin-left & margin-right BUT only if I remove the padding!

I believe I need to get rid of the paragraph element all together and just use the table cell as a text container or even create another table within the cell tag but I'm having troubles styling either of those possibilities. I'm going in a bit of a circle here and need the correct solution that will be compatible with all email clients.

```
<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 4px 0">
                <!-- [ header starts here] -->
                <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:3px solid #E0E0E0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" align="center">
                            <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" width="351" height="51" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                           <p style="border:2px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; background:#F9F9F9; padding: 16px 18px;"> Welcome, {{htmlescape var=$name}}<br /><br />Please look at <a href="{{var product_url}}">{{var product_name}}</a><br /><br />Here is message: <br />{{var message}}<br /><br /></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#E0E4E6" align="center" style="background:#E0E4E6; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0; ">Thank you, {{var sender_name}}</p></center></td>
                    </tr>
<tr><td  style="background:ffffff; height="50"; align="center";>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="{{skin url="images/facebook.png"  _area='frontend' _package="ljj" _theme="can"}}" height="30" width="34" /></a>
<a href="http://www.houzz.com/" target="_blank"><img src="{{skin url="images/houzz.png"  _area='frontend' _package="ljlkj" _theme="can"}}" height="30" width="38" /></a>
<a href="http://instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="{{skin url="images/instragram.png"  _area='frontend' _package="ljlkj" _theme="can"}}" height="30" width="38" /></a>
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><img src="{{skin url="images/pinterest.png"  _area='frontend' _package="ljlkj" _theme="can"}}" height="30" width="34" /></a></td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

body { color:#61777f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

p a {color: #278eb2;}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have there two paragraphs, just remove them.

Replace

```
<td valign="top">
    <p style="border:2px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; background:#F9F9F9; padding: 16px 18px;"> Welcome, ...</p>
</td>
```

for

```
<td valign="top" style="border: 2px solid #e0e0e0; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; background: #f9f9f9; padding: 16px 18px"> Welcome, ...</td>
```

And the same with the second one paragraph:

```
<td bgcolor="#E0E4E6" align="center" style="background:#E0E4E6; text-align:center; font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you, {{var sender_name}}</td>
<!-- <center> isn't necessary here, when you used text-align: center; -->
```

You don't need them in this case.